# glsl vertex shader glGetUniformLocation return null

Tags: javascript, glsl, webgl

hello everyone i'm learning webgl and i can't get the location of the special variable
here is the code

vertex-shader

```
  uniform vec2 u_translation;
  attribute vec2 a_position;
  uniform vec2 u_resolution;
  void main() {
    vec2 position = a_position + u_translation;
    vec2 zeroToOne = a_position / u_resolution;
    vec2 zeroToTwo = zeroToOne * 2.0;
    vec2 clipSpace = zeroToTwo - 1.0;
    gl_Position = vec4(clipSpace * vec2(1, -1), 0, 1);
  }
```

fragment-shader

```
  precision mediump float;
  uniform vec4 u_color;
  void main() {
    gl_FragColor = u_color;
  }
```

```
    var translationLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "u_translation");
    var positionLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "a_position");
    var resolutionLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "u_resolution");
    var colorLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "u_color");
// translationLocation is null  but i can get the others
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6J6sc.png)

does any one know what happend? i think i used the 'u_translation' in the shader

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The local variable `position` is not used anywhere in the shader and thus `u_translation` is not needed and optimized out. So it does not become an active program resource and does not get a uniform location. Likely the following line is wrong

> ```c
> vec2 zeroToOne = a_position / u_resolution;
> ```

but should be

```c
vec2 zeroToOne = position / u_resolution;
```

Now the local variable `position` is used in the shader program and thus `u_translation` becomes an active program resource.